# Compilation error: Argument of \sf@@@subfloat has an extra }. Besite it works well

Tags: graphics, compiling, labels, compilation-error, subfig

I would like to fix errors of compilation, but I do konw how. I would like to could still using labels.

I added code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
some text \ref{fig:label0}\\
some text \ref{fig:label1}\\
some text \ref{fig:label2}\\
some text \ref{fig:label3}\\


\begin{figure}[h]%
\centering
\subfloat[{\centering description A}]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{tmp_img.eps}
\label{fig:label1}}%
\subfloat[{\centering description B}]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{tmp_img.eps}
\label{fig:label2}}%
\subfloat[\centering description C]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{tmp_img.eps}
\label{fig:label3}}%
\caption{Main}
\label{fig:label0}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

```
  Argument of \sf@@@subfloat has an extra }.

 <inserted text> 
                 \par  l.18 \label{fig:label1}}
 % I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
 For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
 this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that I've just
 inserted will cause me to report a runaway argument that might be the
 root of the problem. But if your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and
 it will go away.

 Runaway argument? {\centering description A}]{\@firstoftwo {\nobreak
 \@xcentercr }}\def \ETC. ! Paragraph ended before \sf@@@subfloat was
 complete. <to be read again> 
                    \par  l.18 \label{fig:label1}}
                         %
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text.
How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Result of this code looks like this:
[image]

Comment: If I use `example-image` on an up to date texlive 2019 then this gives no errors, although you get a warning about the bad `\\ ` after `\ref{fig:label3}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Interesting: I do get the error with TeXLive2017.

Comment: @campa pre-history:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sad reality for me. I can't have an up-to-date distribution on the university PC. But what could have changed? I believe `subfig` hasn't been touched for a while, so it must (?) have to do with the kernel...

Comment: @campa fragile command in moving argument answer posted....

Answer (score 3):

It's not the problem of the `label`. Rather you should remove `\centering` from the subfloat description.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
some text \ref{fig:label0}\\
some text \ref{fig:label1}\\
some text \ref{fig:label2}\\
some text \ref{fig:label3}\\


\begin{figure}[h]%
\centering
\subfloat[description A]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{tmp_img.eps}\label{fig:label1}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[description B]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{tmp_img.eps}\label{fig:label2}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[description C]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{tmp_img.eps}\label{fig:label3}}%
\caption{Main}
\label{fig:label0}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works! But when i use very long description, eg. 
`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry` it is not readeble

How I can make space between columns, to make it more readabe?

Answer (score 1):

In the current LaTeX release the document posted in the question runs without error, but in older releases `\centering` was fragile so you need to use `\protect` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
some text \ref{fig:label0}\\
some text \ref{fig:label1}\\
some text \ref{fig:label2}\\
some text \ref{fig:label3}% no\\

\begin{figure}[htp]%
\centering
\subfloat[{\protect\centering description A}]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}
\label{fig:label1}}%
\subfloat[{\protect\centering description B}]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}
\label{fig:label2}}%
\subfloat[\protect\centering description C]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}
\label{fig:label3}}%
\caption{Main}
\label{fig:label0}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, of course... should have thought of _that_ `:-)`

Comment: This works too! But I changed my criteria :D  As I mentioned in [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514235/compilation-error-argument-of-sfsubfloat-has-an-extra-besite-it-works-we#comment1300423_514239) problem is when in description is too long text. I have similar error when I try to use `\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry 
\end{minipage}`

Comment: @nanose well that will be the same. It will work in current releases but need `\protect\begin` and `\protect\end` in old ones.